# center property of ggplot histogram in r plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

```
    df %>%
  filter(include == "TRUE") %>%
  ggplot(aes(var1,fill=re_analysis_dataset))+
  geom_histogram(center = 0.5, binwidth = 0.1)
```

want the histogram center property of ggplot in Plotly please help me with this and I don't want the solution in ggplotly

Comment: Hi Uttam Gogineni. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. First argument of ggplot should be variable with your data. Please take a look at example at: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html. Please edit your question. Thank you.

Comment: @greenmarker the pipe is passing the data frame in as the first argument, so this is the correct use of ggplot.